# TimePicker (react-native-simple-time-picker) not able to set initial Value

Tags: react-native, react-redux, timepicker

I am using TimePicker in react native ([react-native-simple-time-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-time-picker)) and I want to set an initial value 10:47 but I am unable to set. I use property hoursUnit and minutesUnit but its very strange that a zero is appended infront of the value. like for hours its showing "010".

```
  <TimePicker
  hoursUnit="0"
  selectedMinutes="0"
  onChange={(hours, minutes) => this.setState({ selectedHours: hours, 
  selectedMinutes: minutes })}
   />
```

If I set hoursUnit as 10 , value comes 010.

Here is the code that I tried so far:

```
constructor(props) { super(props); 

state = { selectedHours: 10, selectedMinutes: 47, } } 
render (){ 
    return( <TimePicker 
            selectedMinutes={this.selectedMinutes} 
            selectedHours={this.selectedHours} 
            onChange={(hours, minutes) => this.setState({ 
                 selectedHours: hours,  
                 selectedMinutes: minutes })} /> 
) }
```

Comment: Might wanna edit your question and share your code demonstrating how you implemented the prepoulation..

Comment: Surely, I did. Please take a look

Comment: I will - give me a moment..

Comment: Did you see my answer below?

Comment: constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        state = {
          selectedHours: 10,
          selectedMinutes: 47,
        }
  
 }


render (){
return(
<TimePicker
  selectedMinutes={this.selectedMinutes}
  selectedHours={this.selectedHours}
  // onChange={(hours, minutes) => this.setState({ selectedHours: hours, 
  // selectedMinutes: minutes })}
   />
)
}

Comment: even after this it shows the set value as 0,0

Comment: Let me add your code to the question - I'll have a look in a sec..

Comment: I've updated my answer - you need to declare a `const` in your render-statement: `const { selectedHours, selectedMinutes } = this.state;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this issue because you confused `selectedHours` with `hoursUnit` (which is a string for the label of hours) and provided a string for `selectedMinutes` & `selectedHours` - according to the [API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-time-picker#api) the type supposed to be a number. Therefore the API concatenated it to '010', because `'10'` was your label and `selectedHours` defaults to `0` when not provided, hence `'010'`..

In order to get hours and minutes from your state-prop,  you need to declare a `const` in your render-statement: `const { selectedHours, selectedMinutes } = this.state;` (See below for example..).

From the docs:

[image]

To set an initial value, i.E. `10:47` you can try:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedHours: 10,
    selectedMinutes: 47,
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedHours, selectedMinutes } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{selectedHours}:{selectedMinutes}</Text>
        <TimePicker
          selectedHours={selectedHours}
          selectedMinutes={selectedMinutes}
          onChange={(hours, minutes) => this.setState({ selectedHours: hours, selectedMinutes: minutes })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Works When I do this :

```
 <TimePicker
hoursUnit='' // default
selectedMinutes={47}
selectedHours={10}
onChange={(hours, minutes) => this.setState({ selectedHours: hours, 
selectedMinutes: minutes })}
```

/>

Comment: This works because you hard-coded the time - to get it from state,  you need to declare a `const` in your render-statement: `const { selectedHours, selectedMinutes } = this.state;`

Comment: Right, thanks a lot. I have accepted your answer

Comment: It was a pleasure ;)